# How to find max value from array when there is integer,string and special symbol in array without using inbuilt function in php?

Tags: php

How to find max value from array when there is integer,string and special symbol in array without using inbuilt function in php ?

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment of some sort. Normally you'd take advantage of those functions you already have available, it's much easier. But just loop the array, set a variable with the biggest number you find, and overwrite it if you find a bigger number when looping

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array));
```

Comment: thanks but it would be done without inbuilt function

Comment: That looks like built in functions to me. Did you read the question?

Answer (score 0):

`is_numeric` is the PHP Built in method. If you don't want to use that then we have to type cast using `(int)` and check.

```
$arr = [1, 3, -10, 'string', true, [23]];
$max = null;
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (is_numeric($val)) {
       if ($max == null) {
           $max = $val;
       } else if ($val > $max) {
           $max = $val;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can find max value from an array:

```
$array = array('a','b',1,2,'$','^');
$max = $temp = 0;

//This loop is to get max value from array
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {    
   if ($i == 0) {
        $max = $temp = $array[$i];
   }
   if ($i > 0) {
       if ($array[$i] > $temp) {
           $max = $array[$i];
       }
   }
}

print_r($max);
```

Comment: If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is automatically converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Check below link for more details :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Do not add your answer's explanation as a comment.  Please transfer your comment to your answer via an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't do math to a string or Boolean value you could try math and if that fails it's not numeric.

```
$arr = [1, "BBB", 23, -10, 'str', true, false, 50, "@", "$"];
$max = 0;
Foreach ($arr as $v){
    If(!@$v/1==0 && $v>$max) $max =$v;
}

Echo $max;
```

https://3v4l.org/Po31i

If you try "str"/1 you will get the result 0 and an error notice.
The @ suppress the error.

Edit, forgot special symbol in array